# If value is between two other values, do something and continue until it is not. If it is not, try again until it is, then stop when it is not

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a column of dates in a dataframe that begins with yesterday's date and goes through today+13 days. I'm posting this on 2/19/20, so my dates would be from 2/18/20 - 3/3/20.

I need to write a loop that grabs data in a corresponding column if the date in my date column is between today and today+6. I know how to get the data out of the dataframe, but I'm struggling to get the loop right.

Below is an outline of what I'm trying to do

```
df_date = list of dates from dataframe column that I'm checking
current_day = today
seven_day = today + 6

n=0
while df_date[n] >= current_day and df_date[n] <= seven_day:
    grab the data
    n=+1
    continue grabbing data until condition is false, then break
else:
    If the condition is false, add 1 to n until it is true.
    Then grab the data until it is false again and break
```

Comment: There's probably a vectorized/built-in Pandas way of doing this, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dates are in a list, this is pretty simple to do. Assuming everything is `datetime` or `timedelta` objects, the comparisons are also very simple.

I'm using the following setup for this example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# This is so the min_date and max_date have their time portion set to midnight
dt = datetime.today()
min_date = datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
max_date = datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day) + timedelta(days=6)

dates = [
    datetime(2020, 2, 18),
    datetime(2020, 2, 19),
    datetime(2020, 2, 20),
    datetime(2019, 12, 18),  # <-- outside your defined range
    datetime(2020, 2, 21),
    datetime(2020, 2, 22),
    datetime(2020, 2, 23),
]
```

Then, you can just get the dates with a comprehension:

```
>>> [d for d in dates if min_date <= d <= max_date]
[datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 20, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 23, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Perfect problem for a generator:

```
df_date = list of dates from dataframe column that I'm checking
current_day = today
seven_day = today + 6

def grab_dates(df_data, min_date, max_date):
    got_one = False
    for d in df_data:
        if min_date <= d <= max_date:
            yield d
            got_one = True
        elif got_one:
            break

for a_date in grab_dates(df_data, current_day, seven_day):
    print(a_date)
```

Comment: This will stop yielding values once it hits the first date that isn't in the 7-day range.

Comment: The comment line at the end of the original question said "Then grab the data until it is false again and break."  His text didn't say that.  I assumed the comment was correct.  If you simply want to yield each value that's between the two dates, that is a one-line comprehesion.  `(x for x in df_data if min_date  <= x <= maxdate)`